# Hexadecimal numbers in static method calls

Tags: msbuild

Is it possible to somehow use hexadecimal numbers in a static method call in MSBuild? I've tried a few different variations, but I'm getting this error:

> error MSB4186: Invalid static method invocation syntax:
>   "[MSBuild]::BitwiseAnd(0x1, $(FxCopExit))". Input string was not in a
>   correct format. Static method invocation should be of the form:
>   $([FullTypeName]::Method()), e.g. $([System.IO.Path]::Combine('a', 'b')).

I'm trying to do this:

```
<Warning Text="Assembly loading exception" Condition="$([MSBuild]::BitwiseAnd(0x8, $(FxCopExit))) == 0x8"/>
```

It's worth noting that the `0x8` on the right hand side of the condition is acceptable, so if I instead do

```
<Warning Text="Assembly loading exception" Condition="$([MSBuild]::BitwiseAnd(8, $(FxCopExit))) == 0x8"/>
```

Everything works out fine. Since the error codes I'm mapping are defined in hexadecimal, I'd much prefer to keep them in hex here as well, for future readers of the script...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can find out, it is not possible. The only way to keep the hexadecimal is to wrap it in a conversion:

```
<Warning Text="Assembly loading exception" Condition="$([MSBuild]::BitwiseAnd($([System.Convert]::ToInt32(`0x8`, 16)), $(FxCopExit))) == 0x8"/>
```

I'm not sure if this is actually better/more readable than just rewriting the number in decimal and documenting, but this is technically correct, at least...